# How to maintain aspect ratio of HTML buttons between portrait and landscape views?

Tags: html, css

On several devices including iphone 6-8, the aspect ratio of my HTML buttons changes between portrait and landscape views. In the landscape view, the buttons collapse vertically so that they are very thin and the very bottom of the button text is cut off. In the portrait view, it is the opposite, with the buttons becoming fatter vertically than I want them to be. This doesn't happen to the same extent on all devices; on my laptop for example, I can switch between portrait and landscape view by clicking the + sign in the upper-right of the browser window and there is no problem, and in a new expensive iphone the problem is slight.
Here is my current dysfunctional CSS:

```
select {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 110%;
background-color:   #e8ad04;
width: 16%;
min-width: 8em;
min-height:2%;
height: 8%;
margin: 0.3%;
border:3px outset  #e8ad04;
border-radius: 4px;
font-family: "Noto Sans";
font-size: calc(0.6em + 0.65vw);
display: inline-block;
}

input {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 130%;
background-color:  #e8ad04;
width: 16%;
min-width: 8em;
height: 8%;
min-height:2%;
margin: 0.3%;
border:3px outset  #e8ad04;
border-radius: 4px
font-family: "Noto Sans";
font-size: calc(0.6em + 0.65vw);
display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I rectify this behavior?

I considered using images for the buttons, but I don't know how this would work for the Select buttons or even if it would solve the problem.

Comment: I realize that using a percentage for the height probably causes this problem, but I don't know how else to make it adapt to different size screens.

Answer (score 0):

Duh - sorry for being so dumb and any bother. I simply stopped specifying the height in the CSS  - I removed the height: and min-height properties and it works fine.